Forest plot with the forestplot() function
I am making a forest plot with the package forestplot and the function forestplot().
So far I have a plot that works, however, I would like to make some changes to customize it to my liking. So far the working code is:
#Example data
sleep_duration_long_WD_sig <- data.frame(
  Metabolite = c("Met1", "Met2", "Met3"),
  Sleep_factor = c("Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor3"),
  Beta_val_robust = c(0.5, -0.3, 0.7),
  CI_low = c(0.9, -0.5, 0.49),
  CI_high = c(0.8, -0.1, 1.0),
  p_val_robust = c(0.05, 0.001, 0.003)
)

# Code for plot
sleep_duration_long_WD_forest_plot <- sleep_duration_long_WD_sig %>%
  arrange(Beta_val_robust)%>%
  mutate(mean=Beta_val_robust,
         lower = CI_low,
         upper = CI_high)%>%
  mutate(est = sprintf("%.3f [%.3f to %.3f]", 
                        mean, lower, upper), 
         .after = Metabolite) %>%
  mutate(p_val_robust = sprintf("%.3f", p_val_robust)) %>% 
  forestplot(labeltext = c(Metabolite, Sleep_factor, est, p_val_robust), 
             xlab = "Estimate",
             title = "Forest plot",
             boxsize =0.5,
             cex=1)%>%
  fp_set_style(box = "black",
               line = "black") %>%
  fp_add_lines("black") %>%

1: Change order of columns:
In this plot I get the order: Metabolite - sleep parameter - Estimate - p value - forest plot. I would like that the Estimate and p value columns comes after the forest plot.
2: Forest plot color
I would like the ref line at 0 is in dashed red.
3: Increase size of text on x axis
The x axis numbers and title (estimate) is very small, thus I would like it to become bigger.
Thank you for your input!
Best,
Charlie
I have both tried using functions in the forestplot package and functions from ggplot. However, none of it worked.

For 1 I think you will need to use grid package, See the inline comments which addresses 2 and 3. :
sleep_duration_long_WD_sig %>%
  arrange(Beta_val_robust)%>%
  mutate(mean=Beta_val_robust,
         lower = CI_low,
         upper = CI_high)%>%
  mutate(est = sprintf("%.3f [%.3f to %.3f]", 
                       mean, lower, upper), 
         .after = Metabolite) %>%
  mutate(p_val_robust = sprintf("%.3f", p_val_robust)) %>% 
  forestplot(labeltext = c(Metabolite, Sleep_factor, est, p_val_robust), 
             #xlab = "Estimate",
             title = "Forest plot",
             boxsize =0.5,
             cex=1) %>%
  fp_add_header(Metabolite = c("", "Metabolite"),
                Sleep_factor = c("Sleep", "factor"),
                est = c("Estimate", "(CI)"),
                p_val_robust = c("", "P-value")) %>% 
  fp_set_style(box = "black",
               line = "black",
               zero = gpar(col = "red", lty = "dashed"), #2. set the colour red and dashed
               axes = gpar(cex=1.2)                      #3. increase the axis font size
               ) %>%
  fp_add_lines("black")


Edit: Added Estimate as a header, and removed from x-axis labels. I can't find the way of increasing the font size of an x-axis label. gpar only has cex argument, if it had cex.lab we could set the size.

Thank you very much! For the "Estimate", would you do similar within the forestplot()?

@CharlieS see edit, you cant change the xaxis label text size with gpar.
